# I created a game space invaders with multiple enemies

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I wanted to create 1 extra enemy.I have a problem of looping through lists.But I keep getting this error when I do this:

```
   enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
   IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is my code:

```
num_of_enemies = 10
number = 1 
enemyX = []
enemyX_change = []
for i in range(num_of_enemies):
        enemyX.append(i)
        enemyX_change.append(3)

print(len(enemyX))
print(len(enemyX_change))
num_of_enemies += number
for i in range(num_of_enemies):
        enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
```

Comment: Can you `print(len(enemy), len(enemyX_change))` before/in the loop please?

Comment: Yes I tried this and I realized that:
"num_of_enemies += 1"  doesn`t change the length of a list.So how do I change the length of a list every time:
"num_of_enemies"   increases by 1?

Comment: Maybe you could update your list after each modification of `num_of_enemies` so you could be sure the numbers of elements is always the same. If you change your program to OOP (Object Oriented Programming), you could perform the operation inside the `setter` of your variable (but this solution is outside the scope of your question)

Comment: Thank you!But before you answered I figure it out!So I added another variable called: "num_of_enemies_full = 100" , maximum of enemies and I kept adding more enemies

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I fully understand your code.
However, you never `append` elements to your `enemyY` list, but your `num_of_enemies` keep increasing.
Thus, because at time zero, `len(enemyY) = num_of_enemies`, you just need to add one to `num_of_enemies` (did after the first collision occurs),for looking at `enemyY[len(enemyY)]`... obviously this is out of range.

If your number of enemies keep being constant, consider removing the variable `num_of_enemies` (or let it be a constant).
If your number of enemies changes, do not forget to `append` / `pop` elements to your list.

Was this clear or helpful?

Comment: Thanks for your attention it did help me,but I got this error on: enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i],

Comment: If you change the length of `enemy` (*i.e.* the number of enemy), you have too change to the length of `enemy_change` (works for `X` and `Y`).

Comment: Could you edit your initial answer to show the new important part of the code and the errors that goes with? It is tough for me to figure it out without the code nor the error messages...

Comment: I edited my code to show the important part of the code and the error it goes with it.What about now?

Comment: I apologize a lot for the inconvenience... but we haven't enough information now. I had commented your initial question.